# How to make a jQuery function for html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Consider a simple canvas as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
draw();
});
    function draw() {  
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
      if (canvas.getContext) {  
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
        ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);  
      }  
    }
```

How can I introduce variable into the jQuery function to draw several canvases with defined variable (e.g. color set).

In fact, I want to replace canvas id and its options (like color) with variable provided by `draw(variables)`, e.g.`draw(canvas_id, color, ...)`.

**Example:** (for creating several canvases on different DOM elements)

```
    function draw(ccc) {  
      var canvas = document.getElementById(ccc);  
      if (canvas.getContext) {  
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
        ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);  
      }  
    } 

draw(canvas1);
draw(canvas2);
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? If your draw() is in global scope, you can just use some global variables, why bother to introduce variables to `$(document).ready(function(){ draw(); });`?

Comment: @xiaoyi I want to avoid repeating the entire code for each new canvas in the document. I want to have a function with variable. Then for each canvas I need to define `draw(list of variables)`

Comment: Then where do parameters come from? Is that defined manually, calculated based on the context?

Comment: @xiaoyi I added an example of what I meant. The main parameter is the canvas_id.

Comment: @xiaoyi I got your point about `$(document).ready(function(){`; thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  this:

```
function draw(id, clr, fill) {  
      var canvas = document.getElementById(id);  
      if (canvas.getContext) {  
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

        ctx.fillStyle = clr;  
        ctx.fillRect (fill);  

      }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could do it:

```
function draw(colors) {  
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  
  if (canvas.getContext) {  
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

      for(var i=0; i < colors.length; i ++){
          ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];  
          ctx.fillRect (10*i, 10*i, 55, 50);
      } 
  }  
}

// define some colors in an array
var colors = ["rgb(200,0,0)","rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)","rgba(0, 128, 200, 0.5)"];

draw(colors);
```

**EDIT**

Here is [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ufbrr/)